# Error when i try to load mysqldb for jupyter notebook or python shell

Tags: python, mysql, django

Since i changed the connection to a mysql db, i get a error of mysql

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/myophio/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/myophio/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 141, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 369, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 235, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 208, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/MyOphio/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
```

this is my conf:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'myophio_dev',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '192.168.1.84',
    'PORT': '113'
}
```

}

In mysql workbench i can access the data. So, I don't know what is wrong.
I am using a macOS 11. Can you help me?
Python version: 3.10.2

also, i already did `brew install mysql` and `brew reinstall mysql`, `brew restart services mysql`

I dont know what else I can do.

Comment: Have you installed the MySQL package for Python too? `pip install mysqlclient`. Also, _please_ include the full traceback to the error, not just the error message.

Comment: @AKX , Yes, I did that. 
What actually resolved for me, was to do `import pymysql pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()` I don't know why, but im still worried about this.

Comment: pymysql is a separate pure-Python MySQL library and unrelated to `MySQLdb` (which is `mysqlclient` these days). If you do that, you're using it and not `mysqlclient`.

Comment: im still in dev mode. soon, this will be used for production. do you know how can I resolve this mysqlclient error?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the error is, but I suspect it's related to your Mac's development setup. Unless your production environment is a Mac, I doubt it will be very problematic.